# How Memory reservation for x86_64 linux systems works

Tags: linux, memory

I have Dell `PowerEdge R730xd` which is having 1009GB of physical memory and right now there is nothing running still it occupies `6GB` as used.

I guess it has memory reservation which is differently handled for x86_64 systems.

Below is my vmstat output which show free, buff & cached memory.  while `free -g` don't shows buff & cache

```
# vmstat 5 5
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 1052275456  56616 140020    0    0     1     0   10   11  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 1052275456  56616 140020    0    0     0     0  131  217  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 1052275392  56616 140020    0    0     0     0  138  195  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 1052275456  56624 140012    0    0     0     2  408  262  0  0 100  0  0
 1  0      0 1052275520  56624 140020    0    0     0     0  135  189  0  0 100  0  0

# free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1009          6       1003          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:          5       1003
Swap:           63          0         63
```

Comment: Does top confirm that there is nothing running?

Comment: @Raman Yes, and application team 12 hours back shtdown the application ie perforce.

Comment: but if we calculate free+buff+cache it will be close to total.

Comment: The buffers/cache will be used by the kernel for such things as reducing the time taken to write to disks. This can be modified with the sysctl command. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/s-memory-tunables

Comment: @RamanSailopal, that's true, i'm looking for the documentation as such for memory allocation systems which presets these values out of total memory on the systems.